# What numerical integration technique is used for integration of data sets performed in xmgrace?

Tags: xmgrace

From the information on [topic - Integration](http://plasma-gate.weizmann.ac.il/Xmgr/doc/trans.html#int) of xmgrace,

> ... the item marked cumulative sum will construct a set composed of the current value of the integral at a given X. Sum only reports just the value on the next line. ...

I couldn't find information on the integration technique (Trapezoidal rule, Simpson's method ...) which thus motivates the question,

> What numerical integration technique does xmgrace use to integrate the
>   data sets chosen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After downloading the latest **xmgrace (a.k.a. Grace)** [source code](ftp://plasma-gate.weizmann.ac.il/pub/grace/src/) I first searched through all files for the word **"integration"**.  I found a number of methods used for numerical integration. They all lead me to a function called **trapint()**, which is helpfully commented as shown:

```
/*
 * trapezoidal rule
 */
```

It can be found in the file `computils.c` for anyone who wishes to investigate further.

Secondly, when I searched for "Simpson" I did not find anything.

According to [this page](http://faculty.cooper.edu/smyth/TechCompanion/Calc1/Ch08/NumericalIntegration.htm), even MatLab does not have a built-in implementation of Simpson's method (I don't know how recent that page is, but I believe this is still true and couldn't find any other evidence of such a method). 
Therefore, I would not expect xmgrace to have one either, since it is a much smaller program with only a few contributors.

Also, if Simpson's method had been implemented in xmgrace in addition to the Trapezoidal rule method, there would surely be an option in the `Transformations > Integration` menu, so that users could choose which method they wanted.

All this evidence strongly suggests to me that `xmgrace` uses just the Trapezoidal rule for numerical integration. I hope this answer satisfies you.

Comment: +1 A mystery solved finally! It makes sense that trapézoïdal rule would be preferred because "it works" in any number of points, even or odd, even spaced or not. The prize to pay would be the numerical accuracy, which would be a concern for fewer data points. I also found close intégral with trapzoidal rule (home made) than Simpson's rule with xmgrace value.